# Updating multiple values in a single command in clojure

Tags: clojure

If I have

```
(def mymap {"a" {:x 0 :y 0 :z 0}})
```

And I want to increase each of `x`, `y`, `z` in `"a"` by `dX`, `dY`, `dZ` respectively, can I use `update-in` in one command or do I need to do it separately?

Comment: In any case, separate your problem.  Most likely adding deltas to your coordidates can be separate function only solving this problem first. And then if you need to do that with a list or down some nested map is just a problem of getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like `update-coords`:

```clj
(def mymap {"a" {:x 0 :y 0 :z 0}})

(defn update-coords [m dx dy dz]
  (update-in m ["a"] (partial merge-with +) {:x dx :y dy :z dz}))

;; (update-coords mymap 1 2 3)
;; => {"a" {:x 1, :y 2, :z 3}}
```

`update-coords` takes a map `m` and the three deltas `dx`, `dy` and `dz`, and "updates" the entry on the key `"a"` of the map `m` with a function that will perform `merge-with` between the map under the key `"a"` and a new map, with the deltas put in the right places so that the keys overlap. `merge-with` will find the repeated keys `:x`, `:y` and `:z` and will use `+` to produce a new value that will be used in the output. If `mymap` contains extra keys that don't overlap, they are just copied to the output.

Comment: whats the difference when using `update-in` and `partial` to @akond's solution?

Comment: @user3710760 There is not much diffference.  First `update m k` is the same as `update-in m [k]`; next both update and -in take a function and arguments; the function then is called like `f k args` - here a function and the args are used - in the other answer all is done inside the function (no args used)

Answer (score 3):

```
(let [mymap {"a" {:x 10 :y 10 :z 10}}]
    (update mymap "a" (fn [x] (merge-with + x {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}))))
```